# Retrieving the columns based on a condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Input Dataframe:

```
 id typeofAddress       city     state
  1          Home      Kolkata     WB
  2          Home     Columbus     OH
  2        Office    SanFrancisco  CA
  4        Office    Chicago       IL
  4        Home      Chicago       IL
  4        Hotel     Chicago       IL
  4        Other     Chicago       IL
  5
  6        Home                    NY
  7        Office    Edison        NJ
  8        Office    Chicago       IL
  8        Home          
  9        Home
  9        Office
  10       Hotel     Chicago       IL
```

Expected Output:

```
  id typeofAddress       city     state
  1          Home      Kolkata     WB
  2          Home     Columbus     OH
  4          Home     Chicago      IL
  5
  6          Home                  NY
  7        Office    Edison        NJ
  8        Office    Chicago       IL    
  9
  10
```

Actual Output

```
 id typeofAddress       city     state
  1          Home      Kolkata     WB
  2          Home     Columbus     OH
  4          Home     Chicago      IL
  5
  6          Home                  NY
  7        Office    Edison        NJ
  8        Home    Chicago       IL    
  9        Home    
  10       Hotel
```

Explanation :: for id 10 since it is neither Home or Office this row should be picked without anything in typeOfaddress or city or state. The condition is pick the row if typeOfaddress == Home and city not empty otherwise for that id check if typeofaddrees == Office and city not empty otherwise for that id it would be empty .for any other type of address it should be empty

Comment: Just a tip: you might get more interest on your questions if you were to accept answers to more of them. Of course, if you don't think any of the answers to your questions deserve that, then it's your prerogative, but be aware that (rightly or wrongly), many users do judge whether it's worth their while answering questions from profiles that don't seem to engage much with the upvote/accept paradigm of stack overflow. My two cents :-)

Comment: @Corralien ': Thank you for answering the question . In addition to the above condition, I even want to pick the rows where typeOfAddress is blank as well.

Comment: @PiyushSingh. You have rows where typeOfAddress is blank? neither Home or Office?

Comment: yes @Corralien and I want to pick that id

Comment: What is your priority? (Home, city X) > (Office, city X) > (Home, no city) > (no type, city)? Or other?

Comment: @Corralien: Priority1 (Home, city not NULL), Priority2 (Office, city not Null), Priority 3(anyaddressType having blank city)

Comment: @Corralien      id typeofAddress       city     state
  1          Home      Kolkata     WB
  2          Home     Columbus     OH
  2        Office    SanFrancisco  CA
  4        Office  Chicago       IL
  4        Home      Chicago       IL
  4     Hotel     Chicago    IL
  4     Other  Chicago    IL
  5
  6        Home                    NY
  7        Office    Edison        NJ
  8        Office    Chicago       IL
  8        Home          
  9        Home
  9        Office
  10       Hotel     Chicago       IL

Comment: @Corralien : Provide the actual input, expected output and actual output that I am getting

Comment: @Corralien : Type of address would be empty in row 9. My bad in formatting the output. The condition check for Home and office others should be by default ignored and home takes priority over Office.

Comment: Do you need to update your expected output?

Comment: @Corralien Row 9 would have typeOfAddress as Home. rest remains the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240034/discussion-between-piyush-singh-and-corralien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a rank column according your priorities:

```
condlist = [df['typeofAddress'].eq('Home') & df['city'].ne(''),
            df['typeofAddress'].eq('Office') & df['city'].ne('')]
rank = np.select(condlist, choicelist=[1, 2], default=3)

out = df.assign(rank=rank).sort_values('rank') \
        .groupby('id').first() \
        .drop(columns='rank').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   id typeofAddress          city state
0   1          Home       Kolkata    WB
1   2          Home      Columbus    OH
2   3        Office  SanFrancisco    CA
```

Comment: @PiyushSingh, I updated my answer according your comment. Can you check it please. Don't forget to accept an answer if one solves your need.

Comment: @CorralienThe first answer that you provided was solving the problem 80% but in case of an id 4 for eg with empty values was not getting picked.  . Feel free to optimize the code d0 = original data frame
idlist = [1,2,3] ## unique id list
df1= df1[df0['city'].ne('')].sort_values('typeofAddress') \
                        .groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
df2= df0[df0['city'].eq('') & ~df0['id'].isin(idlist)].sort_values('typeofAddress') \
                        .groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

Comment: @PiyushSingh. What do you mean? Can you explain what's wrong with my last code. I can't reproduce a such case. Can you update your post with a modified sample?

Comment: { id typeofAddress       city     state
  1          Home      Kolkata     WB
  2          Home     Columbus     OH
  2        Office    SanFrancisco  CA
  4        Office  Chicago       IL
  4        Home      Chicago       IL
  4     Hotel     Chicago    IL
  4     Other  Chicago    IL
  5
  6        Home                    NY
  7        Office    Edison        NJ
  8        Office    Chicago       IL
  8        Home          
  9        Home
  9        Office
  10       Hotel     Chicago       IL}

Comment: Are you sure for your output of id 9? Explain me the difference with id 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using boolean masks on your DataFrame. You can google "boolean masking with pandas" for more details.

```
import pandas as pd
d={'typeofAddress':['Home','Office','Home','Home','Office'],'city':['Kolkata','Calcutta','Columbus','','SanFrancisco'],'state':['WB','WB','OH','','CA']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
output=df[((df['typeofAddress']=='Home')&(df['city']!=''))|(df['typeofAddress']=='Office')]
output
```